# Quickly check original photo in Lightroom Library module

Tags: lightroom, keyboard-shortcuts

is there a way to quickly check what the original photograph looked like while I'm in the library module of Lightroom?
In particular I would like to be able to check what a photo looked like before cropping, without having to switch to the Develop module.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a way to do exactly what you've described: quickly toggle to the original unedited photo using keyboard shortcuts and without leaving the Library module. It may not be as elegant as you were hoping for but here it is:

- Hit **Ctrl+Shift+R** (**Cmd+Opt+R** on a Mac) to reset all develop settings and revert to the original image.
- Hit **Ctrl+Z** (**Cmd+Z**) to undo that and recover your develop settings.

As I say, not the most elegant solution but it works fine. It's safe too: the reset action just gets added to your develop history, so if you forget to undo you can always come back and do it later.

Those commands are also available on the menu of course:

- Photo > Develop Settings > Reset
- Edit > Undo Reset Settings

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of as of version 5. A list of [known shortcuts](http://members.lightroomqueen.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1358/205/keyboard-shortcuts) can be found on the [Lightroom Queen](http://members.lightroomqueen.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1358/205/keyboard-shortcuts) site, but in a nutshell, before/after previews seems to be Develop module only.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.  Library Grid/Loupe mode can only show you LR's preview. The closest you're going to get is hitting **R**, which will take you directly to Crop mode.  You can then hit **E** to go back to Loupe mode or **G** to go back to Grid mode.

Comment: I initially accepted your answer since it seemed the most fitting, however since yours and also Mark Whitaker's answer both describe wourk-arounds, but his seems a tiny bit simpler, I decided to change.

Answer (score -3):

all you do is simply use the the \ key

Comment: That works in the develop module, but not the library module and, even then, doesn't show before crop. The \ in the library module hides the filter bar.